# CORS enabled on server still receiving header error

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

It seems this is a very popular question, however I have not been able to find a solution that is working

In short, in Chrome, only, I am receiving the following error when making a put, patch, delete, or options request

> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method patch is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

The call works fine in IE and Firefox. Going through postman and swagger also successfully works

In my API I have

```
     public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {   
         services.AddCors();
         return configureMvcServices.ExecuteConfig();
    }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
            app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            var configureApp = new ConfigureApp(app, env);
            configureApp.DoConfig();
}
```

So far I have also tried

- Manually setting the headers
- Creating a policy in the service function and using the the allowcors attribute on the controller consuming said policy name
- Creating a custom middleware per another answer which I cannot seem to find which sets the headers and options

I have also attempted to manually set the headers to accept everything to no avail. There was an answer which I cannot seem to find again to create a middleware but that did not change the outcome. I have also

And I am lost as to how to resolve this issue

Here is the client side code making the call

```
 return fetch(url + path, {
        method,
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'crossDomain':'true',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
```

I do not know what headers I could set on the client side, attempted to change to plain/text but that did not work either if any that could resolve it and I have exhausted my google fu.

additionally gets and posts work just fine

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try this using postman

Comment: yep just chrome has the issue

Comment: You don't need `'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'` in your request. That is a response header sent by the server. Also is `crossDomain` one of your own headers?

Comment: @SimplyGed Oh I know I was trying everything, as for crossDomain that was just something I saw on another answer for this type of problem so was trying it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I cannot explain why but another dev on the team managed to work this out.

In short it appears that Chrome does not like  `AllowAnyMethod()`

and you have to spell out each method

```
  app.UseCors(options =>
               options
               .AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .WithMethods("POST", "GET", "PATCH", "PUT", "DELETE")
           );
```